# How to recover manually deleted boost library files?

Tags: 16.04, apt, dpkg, boost

After playing around with manually installed boost versions to meet software dependencies, I did something stupid: I deleted by system boost libraries (the .so files) from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux.gnu/ . I have tried to remove and reinstall the libboost-all-dev package. I did not get error essages, but the library files were not restored. I have downloaded all the .deb files and installed them manually with dpkg, without success. How can I repair my system and recover the files?

Comment: Are you asking how to determine exactly which package provides a specific file?

Comment: @user535733 I do not know what causes this, so if the files do not come with libboost-all-dev then yes, I'd like to know which other package provides the files. However, that seems implausible. I am facing a severely broken system, I don't want to setup anew, so all help is highly appreciated. The main question is why `apt --reinstall install` does not solve my problem.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the missing filenames, including full paths, from the error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check which Boost-related packages do you have installed.

For example with `dpkg -l | grep boost` and then reinstall all of them with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall \
$(dpkg -l | grep ^ii.*boost | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: @Norbert Thank you so much, this one worked for me! You really saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the package `libboost-all-dev` along with its dependencies. You can find packages which `libboost-all-dev` depends on using the following command in terminal

```
sudo apt-cache depends libboost-all-dev
```

Then reinstall all of them

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libboost-all-dev <list_of_dependencies>
```

Or use two all-in-one commands (try both of them):

```
sudo apt-cache depends libboost-all-dev | grep '[ |](Depends): [^:]' | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d ' ' | xargs sudo apt --reinstall install -y
```

and

```
sudo apt-cache depends libboost-all-dev | grep '[ |]Depends: [^:]' | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d ' ' | xargs sudo apt --reinstall install -y
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This is pretty much along the lines of what I tried already. I got the list, the command apparently did something, but the files are not restored. Any idea how to debug this situation?

Comment: Thanks, I tried both. The first did nothing, the second one did essentially the same as my attempt with the manually compiled dependency list - it loaded some stuff, but the libs did not come back. I worked around the problem in the meantime by compiling boost manually, putting the files in place, and creating a ton of symlinks by hand. However, I'd still like to understand what goes wrong...